# Combinatorics - probability of x boxes containing at least one ball Pr(X=x) putting n balls in N boxes with equal probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I googled and searched on this website, but the question is hard to navigate. If there is a duplicate, please point it to me. Thank you!

I found some similar questions of calculating the expectations. Indeed,
the original question is asking about the expectation of X E(X). I have done it by partitioning X into $\Sigma X_i$($X_i=1$ means i-th box contains at least a ball).

But I was wondering how to calculate Pr(X=x) and count the combinations with x boxes containing ball(s), and I figured out two ways. Nevertheless, I don't know if it's correct or there are any better ways to solve it because it's hard for me to equate the two formulas below.

## 1. (N-x) boxes is unlucky to get the balls, $C_{N,N-x}[(\frac {N-1}{N})^n]^x$

## 2. Just put n balls in x boxes,  $C_{N,x}\frac {x^n}{N^n}$

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking about a particular set of $x$ boxes, or just the general case where at least $N-x$ are empty? If it's the latter, you'll probably have to use the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Not a particular set of x boxes, but exact no matter what x boxes that containing at least one ball, by which I mean x boxes have one or more balls and N-x boxes are empty.

Comment: Try to count the number of ways to select $x$ boxes for the balls, and then the number of ways to place at least one ball in each of these. You may find stars-and-bars helpful here.